# Image button inside div position

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

Hello so i got Div and inside it i got 5 image buttons and buttons are positioning from css how to tell them to position inside div not whole page?

```
 <div>
                <asp:ImageButton CssClass="imgBtn1" ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/zgaszona.png" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" Enabled="False" />
                <asp:ImageButton CssClass="imgBtn2" ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/zgaszona.png" OnClick="ImageButton2_Click" Enabled="False" />
                <asp:ImageButton CssClass="imgBtn3" ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/zgaszona.png" OnClick="ImageButton3_Click" Enabled="False" />
                <asp:ImageButton CssClass="imgBtn4" ID="ImageButton4" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/zgaszona.png" OnClick="ImageButton4_Click" Enabled="False" />
                <asp:ImageButton CssClass="imgBtn5" ID="ImageButton5" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/zgaszona.png" OnClick="ImageButton5_Click" Enabled="False" />
 </div>
```

//Css style

```
body {
}
.imgBtn1 {
position:absolute;
right:0%;
bottom:50%;
top:50%;
}
.imgBtn2 {
position:absolute;
right:25%;
bottom:50%;
top:50%;
}
.imgBtn3 {
position: absolute;
right:50%;
bottom:50%;
top:50%;
}
.imgBtn4 {
position:absolute;
right:75%;
bottom:50%;
top:50%;
}
.imgBtn5 {
position:absolute;
bottom:50%;
top:50%;
left:0%;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The position of the div has to be set to relative

```
    #div_id {
position: relative;
}
```